# How to programmatically remove space after string?

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I am looking to remove the space after the string, for example instead of my vector value being  `SO MILWAUKEE           .xlsx` I would like it to be `SO MILWAUKEE.xlsx`. I am open to a solution in dplyr or base r

```
 [1] "INTERLINE BRANDS.xlsx"         "POLY-AMERICA, LP.xlsx"         "SO TTI POWER EQUIPMENT .xlsx" 
 [4] "GENERAC SO.xlsx"               "SO TOTER LLC           .xlsx"  "SO IMPERIAL INDUSTRIAL .xlsx" 
 [7] "SO MTDARNOLD PRODUCTS .xlsx"   "SO KOHLER GENS.xlsx"           "RUBBERMAID CONSUMER     .xlsx"
[10] "SO MILWAUKEE           .xlsx"  "SO CINDERELLA INC      .xlsx"  "MAKITA                  .xlsx"
[13] "SO  THE TORO COMPANY   .xlsx"  "SO RUBBERMAID SPECIALTY.xlsx"  "SO AMES TRUE TEMPER , I.xlsx" 
[16] "SO POLYWOOD            .xlsx"  "ZEPENFORCER.xlsx"              "TIGER SUPPLIES          .xlsx"
[19] "INTERLINE BRANDS, INC..xlsx"   "SO MWE INVESTMENTS, LLC.xlsx"  "SO DIMPLEX NORTH AMERIC.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data is in `dat`. You could do the following:

```
dat <- gsub("\\s+\\.xlsx", ".xlsx", dat)
```

Comment: While I find it hard to see this breaking based on the sample data, it might be a little more defensive to escape the `.` in `.xlsx` so that the `.` does not match "any character" (as it currently does).

Comment: @r2evans good catch

Comment: (You don't need the backslash-escaping in the second/replacement, only in the first.)

Comment: @r2evans Didn't realize that `replacement` was coerced to character

Comment: There's no coercion, all three args are already character. The `pattern=` (first) argument is the only one that does pattern *matching*; the `replacement=` (second) argument can really only hold placeholders (e.g., `\\1` for grouped/saved-patterns), no other regex in the second is used.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- 
c("INTERLINE BRANDS.xlsx",         "POLY-AMERICA, LP.xlsx",         "SO TTI POWER EQUIPMENT .xlsx",
 "GENERAC SO.xlsx",               "SO TOTER LLC           .xlsx",  "SO IMPERIAL INDUSTRIAL .xlsx", 
 "SO MTDARNOLD PRODUCTS .xlsx",   "SO KOHLER GENS.xlsx",           "RUBBERMAID CONSUMER     .xlsx",
 "SO MILWAUKEE           .xlsx",  "SO CINDERELLA INC      .xlsx",  "MAKITA                  .xlsx",
 "SO  THE TORO COMPANY   .xlsx" , "SO RUBBERMAID SPECIALTY.xlsx",  "SO AMES TRUE TEMPER , I.xlsx" ,
 "SO POLYWOOD            .xlsx",  "ZEPENFORCER.xlsx",              "TIGER SUPPLIES          .xlsx",
 "INTERLINE BRANDS, INC..xlsx",   "SO MWE INVESTMENTS, LLC.xlsx",  "SO DIMPLEX NORTH AMERIC.xlsx")

str_replace(data, '\\s+\\.xlsx', '.xlsx')
#>  [1] "INTERLINE BRANDS.xlsx"        "POLY-AMERICA, LP.xlsx"       
#>  [3] "SO TTI POWER EQUIPMENT.xlsx"  "GENERAC SO.xlsx"             
#>  [5] "SO TOTER LLC.xlsx"            "SO IMPERIAL INDUSTRIAL.xlsx" 
#>  [7] "SO MTDARNOLD PRODUCTS.xlsx"   "SO KOHLER GENS.xlsx"         
#>  [9] "RUBBERMAID CONSUMER.xlsx"     "SO MILWAUKEE.xlsx"           
#> [11] "SO CINDERELLA INC.xlsx"       "MAKITA.xlsx"                 
#> [13] "SO  THE TORO COMPANY.xlsx"    "SO RUBBERMAID SPECIALTY.xlsx"
#> [15] "SO AMES TRUE TEMPER , I.xlsx" "SO POLYWOOD.xlsx"            
#> [17] "ZEPENFORCER.xlsx"             "TIGER SUPPLIES.xlsx"         
#> [19] "INTERLINE BRANDS, INC..xlsx"  "SO MWE INVESTMENTS, LLC.xlsx"
#> [21] "SO DIMPLEX NORTH AMERIC.xlsx"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>